# Adding images to ListView

Tags: asp.net, image, listview

I'm a new entry with ASP.NET and I'm trying to develop a Shop WebSite. I used a ListView to show all the items.

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Hepsiburada.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="IndexItems.aspx.cs" Inherits="IndexItems" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" Runat="Server">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td>

                Welcome <asp:LoginName ID="loginName" runat="server" />
            <asp:LoginStatus ID="chiusuraSessione" LogoutText ="Click here to logout" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="~/LoginPage.aspx" OnLoggingOut="chiusuraSessione_LoggingOut"  />

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="shoppingCartButton" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Size="Large" Height="34px" Text="Shopping Cart" Width="154px"  PostBackUrl="~/Checkout.aspx" />

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="selctItemsLabel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Select Items to buy from the below list of items :"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="formatErrorLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:ListView ID ="ItemsList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="id" onitemcommand="ItemsList_ItemCommand"  >



                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="">


                             <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="addToCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="Add"/>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="priceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="quantityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity") %>' />
                            </td>


                             <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="amountTextBox" runat="server" Text="0" Width="20px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="">
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add">
                        </asp:LinkButton>

                            </td>



                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="idLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="priceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("price") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="quantityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("quantity") %>' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <table runat="server" style="">
                            <tr>
                                <td>No data was returned.</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="">
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                            </td>



                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="idTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="priceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("price") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="quantityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("quantity") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td><asp:Button ID="Buttonbal" runat="server" 
        CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" /></td>

                        </tr>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="">


                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="addToCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="Add" />
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="priceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="quantityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity") %>' />
                            </td>



                             <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="amountTextBox" runat="server" Text="0" Width="20px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <table runat="server">
                            <tr runat="server">
                                <td runat="server">
                                    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                        <tr runat="server" style="">
                                             <th runat="server">  </th>
                                            <th runat="server">id</th>
                                            <th runat="server">name</th>
                                            <th runat="server">price</th>
                                            <th runat="server">quantity</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr runat="server">
                                <td runat="server" style="">
                                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                                        <Fields>
                                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                                        </Fields>
                                    </asp:DataPager>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <SelectedItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="">
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="priceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="quantityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity") %>' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </SelectedItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [items]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</asp:Content>
```

I suppose to have 3 types of items : notebook, pendrive and keyboard. Now I want to add a column to my ListView to show an image for each row. In particular for those items that have an id starting with "111" it must be shown a notebook image, for those items that have an id starting with "222" it must be shown a pendrive image and for those items that have an id starting with "333" it must be shown an keyboard image. It is possible ? I didn't modify the aspx.cs file yet, I just added the ListView control by Visual interface, and I populated it (respect to my database) from there [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/887RU.jpg)], thus I'd like not to "dirty" my project. Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you have a question regarding how to modify your code to do something, please provide your code so that the answers won't have to start from scratch and will be more useful when you receive them. Update the question to include the code, please don't post it as a comment (for readability purposes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call a function in the code-behind to build the image URL:

```
protected static string BuildItemImageUrl(string id)
{
    if (id.StartsWith("111"))
    {
        return "~/images/notebook.jpg";
    }
    if (id.StartsWith("222"))
    {
        return "~/images/pendrive.jpg";
    }
    if (id.StartsWith("333"))
    {
        return "~/images/keyboard.jpg";
    }

    return "~/images/unknown.jpg";
}
```

Call the function from the data-binding statement for the `ImageUrl` of an `Image` control:

```
<asp:Image ID="ItemImage" runat="server"
    ImageUrl='<%# BuildItemImageUrl(Eval("Id", "{0}")) %>'
/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Moreover it says "**Warning Element 'Image' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.**". Where I have to place the Image control?

Comment: @Fabrizio: It needs to be somewhere inside the `ItemTemplate` / `AlternatingItemTemplate`. You'll need to put it inside a `<td>` tag to make it appear within your table.